# Configure VSFTPd with SSL to work correctly with phpseclib

Tags: linux, ssl, php-7, phpseclib, vsftpd

I have a mini Pc Board with ARM64 architecture, Pine64A+. I've installed on board Ubuntu Xenial 16.04

I want to create an FTP Service with VSFTP, with Secure SSL certificate.

Looking on some guides over Internet, I suppose to have VSFTP works fine.
This is my configuration:

```
listen=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
dirlist_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
#local_umask=022
nopriv_user=vsftpd
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
guest_enable=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/var/www/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
hide_ids=YES
guest_username=vsftpd

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_promiscuous=YES
pasv_address=leocric.root.sx
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_min_port=45000
pasv_max_port=45000

xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES

ssl_enable=YES
#implicit_ssl=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=YES
ssl_sslv3=YES
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH

ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
```

The SSL Certificate was generated with the code:

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

At this moment, I think it works fine, because if I use FileZilla I can connect correctly in TLS1.2
But with my PHP code not.

I've used phpseclib with composer installation. The code, I think, works fine because I've tested to another SFTP server.
The code is below:

```
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$sftp = new \phplibsec\Net\SFTP("hostname.tld", 50021);
if(!$sftp->login("user", "pass"))
{
    echo($sftp->isConnected() ? "Login failed!" : "Error establishing connection");
    print_r($sftp->getSFTPErrors());
    die();
}
```

With another Server, I can also upload files, request directory listing, and much more. With my VSFTP Server I got: `Error establishing connection`!

Someone can Help me?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to connect to FTP over SSL. That is **not** what SFTP is. SFTP is SFTP over SSH. It's a distinctly different protocol than FTP. Quoting [wikipedia's entry on SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol):

> SFTP is not FTP run over SSH, but rather a new protocol designed from the ground up by the IETF SECSH working group.

Comment: So, VSFTP is not the good choice to get SFTP, right? What I need to use instead?

Comment: @Klode - I'd just use OpenSSH. `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` should do the trick (assuming it's not installed already).